# For satement in Dafny

Tags: dafny

I'm confused about Dafny's forall statement if the statement inside the forall is to update a variable such as c.arr[i].d, which is mixed with field and array element access. For instance, the example as follows can't be compiled.

I think, explicitly indicating modifies clause is very tedious, I need indicate: modifies top, modifies top.Cache[i]

```
 datatype CACHE_STATE = I| S| E
  datatype MSG_CMD = Empty| ReqS| ReqE| Inv| InvAck| GntS| GntE
  type NODE=nat
  type DATA=nat
type boolean=bool



class  class_0  {
var 
Data : DATA,
Cmd : MSG_CMD
}


class  class_1  {
var 
Data : DATA,
State : CACHE_STATE
}


class TopC{
var
AuxData : DATA,
MemData : DATA,
CurPtr : NODE,
CurCmd : MSG_CMD,
ExGntd : boolean,
ShrSet : array<boolean>,
InvSet : array<boolean>,
Chan3 : array<class_0 > ,
Chan2 : array<class_0 > ,
Chan1 : array<class_0 > ,
Cache : array<class_1 > }







method n_RecvReqS(top:TopC,i:nat, N0:nat )
requires 0<= i<N0
requires top.Chan1.Length ==N0
 requires N0>0
   requires top.InvSet.Length ==N0
 requires N0>0
 requires top.ShrSet.Length ==N0
 requires N0>0
  requires top.Cache.Length ==N0

requires   ((top.Chan1[i].Cmd == ReqS) && (top.CurCmd == Empty))


modifies top.Chan1[i]
modifies top.InvSet
modifies top.ShrSet
modifies top
modifies top.Cache


{
  top.CurCmd := ReqS;
  top.CurPtr := i;
  top.Chan1[i].Cmd := Empty;


  forall j  | 0<= j< N0 {
    top.InvSet[j] := top.ShrSet[j];

  }

  forall j  | 0<= j< N0 {
    top.Cache[j].State:= I;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing about a method's effect on the heap is crucial to verification, though writing `modifies` clauses can be tedious. In your case, you need to account for all of the modifications that method `n_RecvReqS` performs. As you've noted, this includes every `top.Cache[j]` objects, for all `j`'s.

One way to include these in your `modifies` clause is to use a set comprehension:

```
modifies set j | 0 <= j < top.Cache.Length :: top.Cache[j]
```

This denotes the set of the objects `top.Cache[j]`, where `j` ranges among the values satisfying `0 <= j < top.Cache.Length`.

Read on for further options.

If you do this often and you consider all of these caches to be part of the representation of a `TopC` object, then you'll probably want to abstract over the many pieces of your state and put these into a set. If you search the Dafny test suite for declarations like

```
ghost var Repr: set<object>
```

you'll find some examples. Then, your entire `modifies` clause would just be

```
modifies Repr
```

If you're not ready to use such a `Repr` set yet, then there's another simple `modifies` clause you can write for the cache modifications in your program. If you list a *sequence* of objects in a `modifies` clause, Dafny will automatically convert it to the corresponding *set* of objects. You can convert all of the array elements of `top.Cache` into a sequence by the expression `top.Cache[..]`. Thus, to account for the updates in your `forall` statement, you can write

```
modifies top.Cache[..]
```

Unfortunately, Dafny doesn't automatically realize that each `top.Cache[j]` in the body of your `forall` statement is indeed an element of the set formed from the sequence `top.Cache[..]`. It is possible to assist the verifier to help it prove this, but doing so adds some clutter to the `forall` statement. Here's how I did it:

```
forall j | 0 <= j < N0 {
  (assert top.Cache[j] in top.Cache[..]; top.Cache[j]).State:= I;
}
```

Rustan